# jquery Ajax call resulting in Undefined Error in Firefox 18.0.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

$("#btnLogin").click(function () {

```
          if (order != "undefined")
              $.ajax(
                 {
                     type: "POST",
                     data: "{'NewOrder': '" + order + "'}",
                     url: "imgpost.aspx/Update",
                     dataType: "json",
                     contentType: "application/json",
                     processdata: true,
                     beforeSend: function (xhr, data) {
                         console.log(data);
                         alert(data);
                     },
                     success: function (msg) {
                     },
                     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert("Error Occured!" + " | " + XMLHttpRequest + " | " + textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);

                     }
               });
      });
```

Here  ajax call is failed and not redirecting to url : "imgpost.aspx/Update".

XMLHttpRequest and textStatus shows undefined and error respectively.

It occours only in latest update of mozilla 18.0.1

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes around the object.

```
data: {NewOrder: order},
```